# ENOENT error running npm install

Tags: node.js, windows

When I run:

`npm install babel-preset-stage-0`

I get a long ENOENT error.  There are several other npm packages that give me a similar error.

I uninstalled Node.js from Programs and Features.  I reinstalled using the latest LTS (long term support) version.

> npm -v = "2.14.12"
>
> updated to
>
> npm -v = "2.15.1"

The issue remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed the latest stable version (v5.10.1) and the issue is resolved.  Note, the latest stable version is different and a higher version than the latest LTS version.